# angularjs ng-view with outer Controller

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

The linked fiddle contains a simple app, in which i want my variable isLoggedIn to remain updated.
The problem is that the function is called 3 times in a single run.

https://jsfiddle.net/michael_loukeris/xprmoq65/

```
   $scope.isLoggedIn = function(){
    console.log('errr');
  //calling a service

return false;
};
```

What is the best way to achieve 2way data binding in my case so that my navbar remains updated based on user authentication.

Comment: https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/

Answer (score 0):

you should use `ng-show`  with `$scope.variable` not `$scope.function`
because angular will touch  `ng-show`  several times during initialisation.

instead use `ng-init`.

**in your case :**

```
  <ul ng-init='checkUser()'>
    <li><a href="#/this" ng-show="isLoggedIn">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/that">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
```

.

```
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
$scope.checkUser = function(){
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
    console.log('errr');
};
```

Comment: your point of view is to use a function in Main Controller which changes the value of a variable and call it when needed. i did that and works. What i am not sure if its good practice, is that in login subview (i use angular-route) i have to call $scope.$parent.checkUser(); what do you think is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` and it isn't called three times in a run.
Use a variable which is set true/false instead of an function.

Comment: actually is not controller function https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/ this article is really informative